# How to call a method or use a variable from a different namespace in another class in another namespace in a xaml file?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to call a method or use a variable from a different namespace in another class in another namespace in a xaml file?

Comment: Please add sample code, expain what you want expect that happens and the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can add references to namespaces in your xaml root element like this...

```
<UserControl 
  x:Class="MySolution.MyNamespace.MyControl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:another="clr-namespace:MySolution.AnotherNamespace">
```

You can then reference objects from within that namespace in your xaml, for example, I want to bind the Command property of my Button to a command in AnotherNamespace...

```
<Button Command="{x:Static another:MyCommand}"/>
```

I can't really offer much more help than that though without knowing what you actually hope to achieve.